# PERL добавить символ к каждому элементу

Tags: perl

Получаю из формы данные, выбираю те, которые начинаются с `f`

```
foreach my $key (param()) {          
    if ($key =~ /^f(\d+)$/) {                        
        push(@pos, $key);
    }
}
```

После чего я вношу полученный `@pos` в БД и получаю `"f9 f15 f25 f30"`.

Мне же нужно, чтобы в БД попадало `"#f9, #f15, #f25, #f30"`. То есть каждому «слову» добавить в начале `#` и в конце запятую (кроме последнего слова в строке — там запятая не нужна).

Это как-то регексапи делается или как?

Comment: а если вместо `push(@pos, $key);` написать так `push(@pos, "#$key");`

Comment: Да, записывается с решеткой. Но все равно без запятых. Нужно разделить запятыми. Наверно, как-то через join?

Comment: да, после цикла преобразуйте массив в строку вот где то так `my $pos_str = join(", ", @pos);` и использовать $pos_str вместо @pos.

Comment: Спасибо большое :) Как все просто оказывается :)

Comment: perl очень простой язык. и если нужно обрабатывать текст - очень удобный